# Conditionally add json array using jq and bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

Am trying to add a json array with just one array element to a json. And it has to be added only if it does not already exist. 
Example json is below.

```
{
    "lorem": "2.0",
    "ipsum": {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
    },
    "schemes": ["https"],
    "dorum" : "value3" 
}
```

Above is the json, where `"schemes": ["https"],` exists. Am trying to add schemes only if it does not exist using the below code.

```
scheme=$( cat rendertest.json | jq -r '. "schemes" ')
echo $scheme
schem='["https"]'
echo "Scheme is"
echo $schem
if [ -z $scheme ]
then
echo "all good"
else 
jq --argjson argval  "$schem"  '. += { "schemes" : $schem }' rendertest.json > test.json
fi
```

I get the below error in a file when the json array element 'schemes' does not exist. It returns a null and errors out. Any idea where am going wrong?

```
null
Scheme is
["https"]
jq: error: schem/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
. += { "schemes" : $schem }                   
jq: 1 compile error
```

Edit: the question is not about how to pass on bash variables to jq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an explicit `if` condition that checks for the attribute `schemes` in the root level of the JSON structure

```
schem='["https"]'
```

After setting the above variable in your shell, run the following filter

```
jq --argjson argval "$schem" 'if has("schemes")|not then .+= { schemes: $argval } else . end' json
```

The argument immediately after the `--argjson` field is the one that needs to be used in the context of `jq`, but you were trying to use `$schem` in the context which is incorrect.

You can even go one level further and check even if `schemes` is present and if it does *not* contain the value you expect, then make the overwrite. Modify the filter within `'..'` to

```
( has("schemes")|not ) or .schemes != $argval )
```

which can be run as

```
jq --argjson argval "$schem" 'if ( (has("schemes")|not) or .schemes != $argval) then (.schemes: $argval) else . end'
```